# How to access latest torchvision.models (e.g. ViT)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have seen in the [official torchvision docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/master/models.html) that recently vision transformers and the ConvNeXt model families have been added to the PyTorch model zoo. However, even after upgrading to latest torchvision version 0.11.3 (via `pip`) these new models are not available:

```py
>>> import torchvision; torchvision.__version__
'0.11.3+cu102'
>>> import torchvision.models as models
>>> model = models.resnext50_32x4d()  # previous models work fine
>>> model = models.vit_b_16()  # vision transformers don't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torchvision.models' has no attribute 'vit_b_16'
```

Any ideas how I can access these latest model additions in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event though @Shai's answer is a nice addition, my original question was how I could access the official ViT and ConvNeXt models in `torchvision.models`. As it turned out the answer was simply to wait. So for the records: After upgrading to latest `torchvision` pip package in version 0.12 I got these new models as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I had the same issue for ViT and ConvNeXt and by following your suggestion, it is working. Here is the update command that I have used (on google colab): `pip install --upgrade torch torchvision`

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of getting pytorch models besides `torchvision`.
You should look at [`torch.hub`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html?highlight=hub#module-torch.hub) for getting models from specific github repos that enabled sharing via this interface.

Additionally, you have [`timm`](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-pytorch-image-models-timm-a-practitioners-guide-4e77b4bf9055) -- a repository for many pytorch vision models.

for example:

```py
# list all ViT models
timm.list_models('vit_*')
# list all convNext models
timm.list_models('convnext*')

# load ViT-B/16
vit_b_16 = timm.create_model('vit_base_patch16_224', pretrained=True)
# load conv next
convnext = timm.create_model('convnext_base', pretrained=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the `timm` module. However, if I don't want to make use of the "official" torchvision models, how can I access them as asked in my original question?

Comment: @Matthias  not all models published in conferences make it to torchvision.models...